# How can I uninstall Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am following a tutorial about Ruby on Rails, and the tutorial got updated to a new version of Rails, so I can't follow it anymore because I have an older version.

I would like to start new and uninstall Ruby on Rails and any related software on my Mac OS X 10.5.8, and follow it from ground up. If anyone would be willing to help me uninstall Ruby and Ruby on Rails, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Download [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [RBENV](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) and upgrade to the latest Ruby (2.3.0 at this point). Don't touch your system Ruby.

Comment: RVM is definitely the way to go

Comment: I agree with both of the above. RVM is the way to go. You will not need to use "sudo" at all when installing unless you are doing it site-wide, so resist all urges to do so. RVM will create a sandbox for all Rubies installed using it, which will cause the gems loaded with one of those Rubyies to also be in the sandbox. Removing a Ruby is easy at that point.

Comment: I used RVM. And got to install the latest Ruby and Ruby on Rails. So far there's no problem and I get on with the tutorial just fine. I might still want to uninstall the old version though. How do I check if the old one is still installed?

Comment: Try:
`rvm use system`
and
`gem list`

Comment: WARNING! this is really dangerous as it will mess up your system ruby installation. using rvm or other version managers you will be able to install a new version and use that while leaving your systems underlying ruby installation intact... tread carefully.

Comment: @domji84 Good call. This answer is definitely showing age and the correct steps are to leave system Ruby and install RMV or RBENV or a different ruby version control system.

Comment: Rbenv is a better-structured solution than rvm. Just do you know.

Comment: And to add to the layers of answers here, chruby is a lighter Ruby switcher than both rbenv and rvm.

Comment: Thank you very much. I installed rvm, ran `rvm install ruby` and then I no longer had trouble installing rails

Comment: This touches on it but does not clearly answer the question asked. Instead it simply points to links.

Answer (score 3):

Are you uninstalling Ruby on Rails, or Ruby *AND* Ruby on Rails?

If you want to uninstall Ruby on Rails it should be a simple matter of using `gem uninstall rails` or doing `gem dependency rails` and then `gem uninstall` for each of the listed gems that Rails depends on. If you installed them system-wide, using `sudo` originally, you'll have to use `sudo` again to uninstall them.

If you want to uninstall a system-wide Ruby you installed from source, well, I'd probably leave it alone and install any new versions of Ruby using RVM. The older version won't be visible to apps unless you want them to see it or set your path to include it. RVM's version will be found first unless you do `rvm system`.

Actually you could simply install RVM and have it install your new versions of Ruby, then from there install new versions of Rails, without even bothering to uninstall the old stuff. RVM really is that cool.

Comment: Awesome. I like RVM. Yes I do want to uninstall RoR and Ruby. Is there way of checking if I still have the old version installed? I got the RVM working.

Comment: @Jeff, Usually a non-system installed Ruby compiled from source will be in `/usr/local/bin` and I think `/usr/local/lib`. One installed from a .dmg would be in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework` followed by the version number. How did you install the old version of Ruby, by .dmg-based installer or from source? Do not remove the system installed version in `/usr/bin`. Do `rvm system` followed by `which ruby` and see what shows up.