# Whenever gem in rails error :'to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst

Tags: rake, task, scheduling, whenever

I am using whenever gem in my application. And i have scheduled a rake task every 5 minutes. But that rake task is not running every 5 minutes. When i saw the log it gave me error like

> `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0,
>   io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4]
>   (Gem::LoadError)

this is the content in schedule.rb

```
every 3.minutes do
    rake "mytask name"
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue solved by putting

```
env :PATH, '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin'
```

instead of

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
```

on the top of config/schedule.rb

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs whenever we changes in your gem file, specially **rails / ruby** version.
I was facing this same issue, here is what I did to get rid of that-

```
 1. $ gem install bundle
 2. $ bundle install
```

Now everything working fine.

> If you are getting same issue as-

```
`to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 23 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

[then here are the steps-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties)
See the link as-
[Rails: Could not find railties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties)

```
 1. $ gem list
 2. $ gem install rails
```

It will just download all missing dependencies, including railties.

Hope this will work for you too !!!