# can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've seen a few other issues for this, tried their recommendations, none of them worked for me.

I've been using Rails for about a year, just started a new Rails project, and suddenly having issues. I uninstalled and tried reinstalling all of Ruby and Rails. Ruby is fine, but not Rails.

When I enter `rails s`, I get the `can't find gem railties`. My current Ruby version is `ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin15]`, even though I've been trying to set ruby 2.3.0 through rbenv.

If I try `rails -v` to see what version I'm running, I get the same error. I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6.

Comment: maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212116/rails-could-not-find-railties

Comment: @sakurashinken I tried that, and it just lead to other errors... which just got me back to the original.

Comment: try `bundle install`

Answer (score 12):

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs
rvm cleanup all
rvm reset
```

It works for me! Maybe some commands useless, I just retell the history of my shell :)

Comment: Thank You!!!! This actually worked! I have been on it forHOURS! 

Answer (score 4):

Below is some step by step to install rails with RBENV, probably you can follow along, what command that probably you missed

1. ### rbenv versions

   - check your rbenv version
   - if you think you need to upgrade you can use command below
   - **brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build**
2. ### rbenv install -l

   - check list of ruby that can be installed with rbenv
3. ### rbenv install 2.3.1

   - this is sample to install ruby version 2.3.1
   - ruby will be copied to /Users/%your_user_name%/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1
   - this is just sample version, use the latest / stable from command number 2
4. ### rbenv rehash

   - this command will apply new ruby version that you just install
   - after you install / reinstall ruby with rbenv don't forget to run this command
   - this is important one, that most of developers forget to apply
5. ### rbenv global 2.3.1

   - set global ruby to version 2.3.1
6. ### rbenv local 2.2.2

   - after you set global (with version 2.3.1) in case you want specific folder with version 2.2.2 you can set local folder with this command
7. ### gem install bundler

   - within your active ruby this will install bundler software for specific version
   - again after you run this do not forget to run ##rbenv rehash##
8. ### gem install rails##

   - this will install rails (latest)
   - although there are no Gemfile this will install rails
   - if you like to install specific version you can use Gemfile  and run command number 7 (below)
9. ### bundle install

   - this will install rails including all dependency
   - again if you not sure / some command not work please try ##rbenv rehash##

Comment: maybe a `bundle update --bundler` is needed if those steps are still not working.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I can get it to work using bundle exec rails s. It's not ideal, but, if that's what it takes I'll just keep using bundle exec rails s.

UPDATE: This no longer works, it was only temporary. I had rbenv installed, and no matter what version I tried to set as local or global, it didn't set. Turned out, that my path was messed up, and it was hitting usr/local/bin first rather than hitting .rbenv first. Someone was able to help me offline. :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me while i have been using Ubuntu 16.04.

Make sure that rvm(Ruby version manager) is accessible to your terminal, by simply execute command

```
 $ rvm -v
```

Now run following commands=>

```
$ rvm gemset list
```

Output of above command will be

---

gemsets for ruby-2.5.3 (found in /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3)

=>(default)

carserv

global

---

Now set correct gemset instead of default. in my project it is **carserv**.
For that use following command

```
$ rvm gemset use carserv
```

It's time to start your rails server.

```
$ rails server
```

I hope this process will help you. :)