# Getting error while running rails command "rails _5.1.0_ new test1" at root level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running the below command in command prompt but getting the following error:

```
Command: rails _5.1.0_ new test1
```

Error:

```
C:\>rails _5.1.0_ new test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (= 5.1.0) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731592/cant-find-gem-railties-0-a-gemgemnotfoundexception

Comment: No luck @SaraTibbetts

Answer (score 0):

you don't have rails 5.1.0 installed on your system

first, install rails 5.1.0 with `gem install rails -v 5.1.0`

then `rails _5.1.0_ new test1`