# Uninstall old ruby version completely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, uninstallation

So I have ruby-2.2.1 and ruby-2.2.3 installed on my mac.

I run $ rvm remove rbx-2.2.1 to uninstall Ruby 2.2.1 but when I run $ rvm list , I still get ruby-2.2.1 [ missing bin/ruby ] and ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ].

I tried uninstall commands but nothing works out. Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even want to do that? I suggest you to follow this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115803/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-os-x/4115811#4115811
As you already have `rvm`, just install your required ruby version and use that. Don't touch your system ruby.

Comment: I tried reload but didn't work :(