# Rails Installation/Startup Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a mistake earlier today where I ran a `git clean -f` command and it seems to have wiped out rails and rvm. I tried to re-install both, and the installations seemed to work, but when I try to run the `rails -v` I get a gem load error. This tells me that the installation did not work properly, even though I watched railties get installed a few minutes ago. Does anyone have any advice for this sitation? Or do you have experience troubleshooting an error like this?

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in`to_specs': `Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 19 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in`to_spec'
`from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in`gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'`

Comment: did you bundle after installing?

Answer (score 0):

try the simple stuff first, bundle install, restoring from git depending on what your branches were. Finally you made need to just uninstall and reinstall

[How can I uninstall Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115803/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-os-x/4115811#4115811)

https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/rvm-implode-and-rvm-install/